# How to delay execution of onPostExecute() method till api calls are complete

Tags: android-asynctask, async-await, android-volley, delayed-execution

Am making an api call from asynctask's doInBackground() method. I want asynctask to execute onPostExecute() method only after receiving response of this api call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The default functionality of AsyncTask is, `onPostExecute()` will be called only when `doInBAckground()` method is completed.

If this is not happening, please share the code.

Comment: That's true. But the api will take time to complete ryt, depending on the internet speed. By default functionality, as soon as api call is fired, onPostExecute is executed. I want to delay that.

Comment: onPostExecute() will be called only after getting the api response. If it's not happening, you are doing asynchronous call to api in asynctask. Please share the code, I can help you